# Process - waiting till it´s over

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I´m using process like this

```
      System.Diagnostics.Process prc1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
      prc1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
      prc1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe";
      prc1.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c C:\app.exe -f C:\appConfigs.cfg ";
      prc1.Start();
      prc1.CloseMainWindow();
```

So this will open a MSDos window and it will keep it open until the "job" it´s finished,
So far so good, But what if I want, after this code, let´s say put a message to user saying "Job Finished", is there a way to know when it´s finished? (when the dos windows is closed?)

I could use a timer but the time it takes depends on the amount of information that i need to process.

Comment: Process has an [Exited event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can hook into :

Comment: [Process.WaitForExit Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx) do some reading / research on this

Comment: I used the process.Exited and I solved my problem .. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the `Exited` event. If all you wanted to do was display a message, you could specify it on a single line like this:

```
prc1.Exited += (s, a) => MessageBox.Show("Job Finished");
```